# Dynamic galleryview

Tags: jquery, dom, galleryview

I am using jquery [galleryview](http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview/) plugin. 
I want to update the already created galleryview object with the new images. 
I am trying to figure out the dom element which stores and changes these images.
Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the images are handled via the CSS file. Open up the CSS file and locate the following calls:

.gv_navPlay, .gv_navPause, .gv_navNext and .gv_navPrev

You can also change the images being called up there, as well.